# How to avoid "-internal-autofill-selected" style to be applied?

Tags: css, google-chrome

I have a login form with 2 fields, username and password. Username field is autocompleted by chrome. When I submit the form (when it is valid), this style is applied mysteriously:

```
input:-internal-autofill-selected {s ñ
    background-color: rgb(232, 240, 254) !important;
    background-image: none !important;
    color: -internal-light-dark-color(black, white) !important;
}
```

Is there a way to avoid that? The form is submitted using Ajax, so it is a little ugly if for Username field that style is applied, but for Password field it is not.

I noticed that this happen only if field is filled with an element in the chrome sugggestions list. If field is filled with a value that is not in the list, the style is not applied.

Regards
Jaime

Answer (score 127, accepted):

To get rid of the undesired behavior, this trick "just works" (tm):

```
  input:-webkit-autofill,
  input:-webkit-autofill:focus {
    transition: background-color 0s 600000s, color 0s 600000s !important;
  }
```

EDIT: As @Spock mentioned in a comment, you may want to increase specificity of this styling in case there's a competing setting coming from another library. Thus, adding `!important` to the snippet above to make sure it works as-is for a wider audience.

Comment: I'm wondering though, why it's not working setting bg color & color to "unset"?

Comment: will someone please blog about... whyyyyiiieee? caveats? Will a chrome update obliterate this one day? Why do y'all happily copy/paste and walk away? Laaaawd help us.

Comment: @RonGilchrist we are in the hands of Blink (the rendering engine behind Chrome) developers all the time, and this time is not any different. The solution above postpones any styles applied by Blink in our specific case by the period of 10000 minutes. It might stop working in the future, but I personally consider that highly unlikely. What is more likely is a proper (not stopgap) solution emerging at some point.

Comment: Doesn't work in new versions of Chrome

Comment: @agon024 I cannot confirm - it still works in my just-updated Chrome, no issues

Comment: This answer allows the 'background-image: none !important;' style to be applied.  The answer by @Florian Weber worked best for me as input fields that are valid/invalid with Bootstrap are updated with a background-image.

Comment: you probably want to swap the large and zero numbers around:

```transition: background-color 0s 600000s, color 0s 600000s ;```

it's not the animation that should take 600'000 seconds, but the delay, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition. Also, you probably want to avoid for the animation engine to run and waste those cycles unnecessarily!

Comment: @LoftyLion thank you mate, I have made the edit. I somehow mismatched the values

Comment: none of these answers are working what a dumbass design decision

Comment: @Ruben it certainly is still working for me. Note though, it relates just to the built-in Chrome mechanics, and has nothing to do with 3rd-party extensions like LastPass etc - those extensions could do to the page absolutely whatever they want and I don't think a universal workaround is possible in that case.

Comment: Amazing, finally something that worked! Thanks a bunch.

Comment: @Ruben I found that I also had old styling where I tried to set the  color in other ways.  Try to remove all styling code you have before, that tried to manipulate it. That did the trick for me. Also add !important to the rule

Answer (score 29):

The answer is not intuitive. It's more a trick than anything else but it looks like it's the only one that works:

```
input:-webkit-autofill {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px yellow inset;
}
```

This will style a `yellow` background to you input. It's basically a very opaque and overwhelming inner shadow. They use the same trick in the [link](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/change-autocomplete-styles-webkit-browsers/) @ravb79 sent.

Comment: well, that killed a couple of my minutes from my life

Answer (score 21):

If you're ok with the default `-internal-autofill-selected` styling on a light theme and just want it to look nicer in a dark theme then you might just need:

```
input {
  color-scheme: dark;
}
```

Comment: There are some browsers that somehow don't support the other solutions, in that case this worked fine for me

Comment: This is the BEST solution for "dark mode" IMO because it targets the browser's behavior instead of using a workaround with css animations.

Answer (score 8):

I tried overwriting the style but for some reason it didn't work at all. Webkit or at least chrome just ignored that style.

When I added !important to the style webkit / chrome just flat-out removed it from the equation entirely. Nowhere to be seen in the element inspector.

Everything I tried got either ignored or removed.

Sooo, I came up with this horrible bullshit. But it works so far.

```
// Fix autocomplete shit
function fix_autocomplete_shit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        if ($(this).is(':-internal-autofill-selected')) {
            var clone = $(this).clone(true, true);
            $(this).after(clone);
            $(this).remove();
        }
    }, 10);
}
$('.form-control').on('input', fix_autocomplete_shit);
```

I'm using bootstrap and I want to keep validation icons in form of background-images.

Only god knows why the webkit creators thought they absolutely have to set background-image to none but if they want war they can have it.

Comment: Though this isn't my favourite answer, it is my favourite function name. Have +1

Comment: Don't use jQuery. It's not 2006 anymore! ES6 has made jQuery irrelevant (by adopting much of it's syntax and structure).

Answer (score 7):

You can add a box-shadow to remove the blue background

```
box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0), inset 0 0 0 100px rgba(255, 255, 255,1);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just add your own CSS so the updated state matches your regular input state. Adding an extra class to your declaration together with the !important attribute should override it.

So:

```
input.my-input {
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255) !important;
    background-image: none !important;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0) !important;
}

input.my-input:-internal-autofill-selected {
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255) !important;
    background-image: none !important;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0) !important;
}
```

I also found this btw: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/change-autocomplete-styles-webkit-browsers/

Answer (score 1):

I slightly tweaked @kostiantyn-ko's answer to only be applied to invalid inputs.

Sass:

```scss
input {
  &:is(:invalid, [aria-invalid=true]) {
    // your error styles
    background-color: var(--color-background-critical-subdued);
    border: 1px solid var(--color-border-critical-subdued);

    // hack needed to get rid of autofill styles only on invalid forms
    &:is(:-webkit-autofill, :-webkit-autofill:focus) {
      transition: background-color 600000s 0s, color 600000s 0s;
    }
  }
}
```

CSS:

```css
/* your error styles */
input:is(:invalid, [aria-invalid=true]) {
  background-color: var(--color-background-critical-subdued);
  border: 1px solid var(--color-border-critical-subdued);
}

/* hack needed to get rid of autofill styles only on invalid forms */
input:is(:invalid, [aria-invalid=true]):is(:-webkit-autofill, :-webkit-autofill:focus) {
  transition: background-color 600000s 0s, color 600000s 0s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This way should work (Remember to switch styles as needed):

```css
input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:hover, 
input:-webkit-autofill:focus {
    border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
    -webkit-text-fill-color: #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px rgb(232, 240, 254) inset;
    transition: background-color 5000s ease-in-out 0s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried many of the above-mentioned solutions, but nothing worked for me. But then stumbled upon a new `input` psudeo called `:autofill`

```
:root {
   --background-color: #000; // you can use any color, mine was #000
}

input:autofill {
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 100px var(--background-color);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Incase anyone is still looking for a solution... This worked for me.

```css
.inputDiv input.filled-input:-webkit-autofill,
 .inputDiv input.filled-input {
    -webkit-background-clip: text !important;
    background-clip: text !important;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 100px var(--filled-color);
    outline: var(--border) var(--secondary-color) !important;
}
```