# Input background (image) gets removed after selection of suggestion

Tags: html, css

I have email input with background image as symbol on it. The issue is input works properly if user adds data but if they choose to select suggestions provide by browser, the image just hides.

See below HTML and CSS.

```css
.login-form-email {
    border-radius: 6px;
    background-color: #fff;
    background: url(img/envelop.png) no-repeat scroll 7px 7px;
    padding-left: 40px;
}
```

```html
 <div class="form-group">
    <label class="short-description"> Email </label>
    <input id="username" name="username" type="text" class="form-control login-form-email" autocomplete="off" required>
</div>
```

This snippet might not work but I'll add snapshot of how it looks.

Here is the image 1 on how it looks initially. [image]

Now, when I select the autosuggestion, it weirdly looks like this. (See envelop symbol is removed.) [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap `<input/>` element in `<div>` and add styles to `div::before`. if you do it in this way, your `input` will be `responsive` also.

With `-webkit-autofill` you can change autocomplete styles in Webkit browsers.

```css
.input-wrapper{
 display: inline-block;
 margin-left:-25px;
}
.input-wrapper::before {
    content: "";
    background: url(https://img.icons8.com/external-justicon-flat-justicon/64/000000/external-email-notifications-justicon-flat-justicon.png) no-repeat scroll 0px 0px;
    background-size: 20px 20px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    position: relative;
    left: 15%;
}
.login-form-email{
     border-radius: 6px;
     padding:5px 10px 5px 28px;
}
.form-control:-webkit-autofill,
.form-control:-webkit-autofill:hover,
.form-control:-webkit-autofill:focus,
.form-control:-webkit-autofill:active {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 30px white inset !important;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 30px white inset !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
      <label class="short-description" for="email"> Email </label>
      <div class="input-wrapper">
        <input
          id="email"
          name="email"
          type="email"
          class="form-control login-form-email"
          required
        />
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: You're welcome Bharat, it's my pleasure.

Answer (score 1):

this is because of when you select the suggestion value it will be autofill the field and the browser has the default autofill `background` property.

you have used the sort-hand property for the `background` so when you autofill the field value the `background` property will changed.

please use separated properties for that like this way.

```
.login-form-email {
    border-radius: 6px;
    background-color: #fff;
    background-image: url(img/envelop.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 7px 7px;
    padding-left: 40px;
}
```

Comment: it's separate but browser makes it together. something else needed to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that currently the browser's default styling for this can not be overridden, or there is no direct solution to do so, see here:
[How to avoid "-internal-autofill-selected" style to be applied?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61083813/how-to-avoid-internal-autofill-selected-style-to-be-applied)

The alternative solution is to use a `before` element, like so:

```css
.form-group:before {
    content: "";
    background: url(https://emojipedia-us.s3.amazonaws.com/source/skype/289/envelope_2709-fe0f.png) no-repeat scroll 0px 0px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    background-size: 20px 20px;
    z-index: 999;
    position: relative;
    left: 65px;
}
.login-form-email{
    text-indent: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="short-description"> Email </label>
    <input id="username" name="username" type="text" class="form-control login-form-email" autocomplete="off" required>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to change the background color of auto-filled input you need to use these:

**UPDATED:**

```
input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:hover, 
input:-webkit-autofill:focus, 
input:-webkit-autofill:active{
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 30px white inset !important;
    background: url(https://img.icons8.com/external-justicon-flat-justicon/64/000000/external-email-notifications-justicon-flat-justicon.png) no-repeat scroll 0px 0px;
background-size: 20px 20px;
}
```

Comment: it updates the color but not keeps the image.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered a problem where `background-color` property was changing `-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 30px white inset !important;` but the background-image applied to the input element(icon in my case) wasn't showing when the browser autofill option selected. To resolve this I came up with this solution.

```
$("#username").on('blur', function(e) {
    if(this.matches(':-webkit-autofill')) {
        var value = $(this).val();
        $(this).val('');
        setTimeout(() => {
            $(this).val(value); // Restore the original value
        }, 10);
    }
});
```