# How do I change formatting of an input field after selecting an item from a drop-down menu?

Tags: html, css, forms, input, formatting

I'm trying to figure out how to set my own colors for when a user selects an item from a drop-down menu. This drop-down is suggested by the browser and isn't implemented in the html.

Here, I selected a suggestion from the drop-down in the "name" input field and its been given this bright purple color. I need to change this color to go with the rest of the website.

form input color change:

[image: form input color change]

I tried the ::selection pseudo-class but didn't work

Comment: I recommend uploading a screenshot with the purple that you don't want to see to contrast with the screenshot of what you want to see.

Answer (score 0):

There are some questions about that:

- [How to avoid "-internal-autofill-selected" style to be applied?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61083813/how-to-avoid-internal-autofill-selected-style-to-be-applied)
- [Removing input background colour for Chrome autocomplete?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2781549/removing-input-background-colour-for-chrome-autocomplete)

You can search for additional info on the internet using the keywords 'browser autofill background color'.

Comment: That's what I was looking for!
I didn't know what to search. Thanks a lot.